# Vega click param on a single layer being applied to all layers

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I can't for the life of my figure out what is going on here. Basically, I have a vega chart and I want to only enable clicking on the points, not the lines (because it seems that when I enable clicking on the lines, the timestamp is off - I end up with the timestamp of the beginning of the chart instead of that segment for some reason). I have separate layers for my points and my lines. It seems to me that it should be easy - simply create a click event for each of the point layers, and do nothing to the line layers. However, I have found that the click events created on any one layer are actually applied to ALL the layers for some reason. i.e. if I create a click event param for each point layer, all three of them fire whenever you click on any of the points. So I decided to just create one click event on one of the layers instead. However, this event also fires when you click on the lines! I somehow can't disable the line clicking no matter what I try. Worse, there is no way to distinguish between the line clicks and the point clicks in the frontend, so I can't even filter them out. Desperate for a solution.

Here is my Vega-lite json: [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-0BwNBGsdWkj2LYanZUAIne7Su6vTqVattdtDabVr37EPTpoAC9+l2QCXldo-rYAH0IHjRN+0tLQAEcGFyQ44hoUht2bOMEzgJNT2-Htfx0BhAI2WRo0ma9IOg2w6DghCHWbSN8ImdCf2sf9MAA4wwwOcD0CgmCyJ8CjG01K0Q1YwYkRqV4TADUBkCMCVzXYkBhEMUxdgMeI8UEAkkRGMZaIxEBVlkwcQE40jXXgq8MPPdBsMA4CULQyirQAFRyWF2QAYUY9kCHZJoxVaTs-1NcTvTiCItGQ0CArYHAkCgOh9N04gKgRNAkkoAAODJMkk94ZN0gcrWU2wDnzHx1VQeFCW0dczXQIrthMTTRgPHTQAS9w5OM2CePM+irMYoCQNQ-t+K0ZzYrgdzPO83zLwCk1apCt0inQCLhqimK4otUIksEFLUDSzKkRinIEHRUowiQK5rGEKAZKUAljg7fK5Pq0wf3OkBy0rRtkyUOQbpoO6RQGbKQCkvKOsMhTzLeiqjARJrtJjXT2sbTqSO6sz3swhicKYvCCPmrxFpAFcwp1KNaKRaLYvinbks2Q6sq-CGDMKtgVJKrwyrQSqlCqAFapAeqHCRlqUba9niK40zeL6v98YAwnqYFkngrJ0KVpbKmYxpzb6cSxnUoylmcuk6X0BhpTOeK+HEeGZqidRy2jMx7jsYZXH+qVlizWNdXQnJ7XBP9-6De2o29qZygxDN8Hctdt68x5wt7aqwWZHEkXbYagKtIlyYXZewyuo9+XvcVwC-catWgqDrWtFD2uQFpra0d2-a0rjjJQaAA)

Comment: Hi John, Can you add some data to your spec?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out why the events are being applied to all layers. However, I was finally able to disable clicking on the lines by changing the param to the following:

```
"params": [
    {
      "name": "click",
      "select": {
        "type": "point",
        "fields": ["group", "ts"],
        "on": {
          "type": "click",
          "source": "scope",
          "marktype": "symbol"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```